# React Typescript and inline if statements to establish type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My aim is to display a component when data is available.

The data is regularly fetched from an API by the parent component and stored in state. It is then passed as a 'data' prop to the child component.

The works well if a placeholder of the valid type is defined in state at the constructor stage.

But when it is not possible to include a placeholder of the valid type I run into issues.

If I include the following in render still get Type Error.

```
{typeof this.state.tracker !== 'undefined' ? <Tracker data={this.state.tracker} /> : ''}
```

TypeScript error: Type 'TrackerInterface | undefined' is not assignable to type 'TrackerInterface'.

It is my understanding that TypeScript knows when a type is excluded by an if statement.

Your guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you set the `tracker` state to `null`, and use `defaultProps` inside the `<Tracker/>` component to initialize the prop and do a conditional render?

Comment: This is interesting. According to the docs I've found, it should actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like that:

Data is passing to your Component as an union of IDataType|undefined.

```
export interface IProps {
    data?: IDataType;
}

function Component(props: IProps) {
    return (<div>
        { data && <Tracker data={props.data} }
    </div>);
}
```

Comment: It's in a class so I assume this would translate to? {this.props.data && <Tracker data={this.state.tracker}/>}. this gives me TypeScript error: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

Comment: In your code it should not be {this.state.tracker && <Tracker data={this.state.tracker} />} ?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try initializing the state of your parent component to `null` and pass it to `<Tracker/>`.

Define

```
Tracker.defaultProps = {
    data: <Some valid data>
}
```

You can then check the prop in the `render` function of `Tracker` and conditionally render some loading state/ whatever suits your needs.